# nginx rewrite url regulation with regex

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

nginx rewrite url regulation with regex 
url like this

```
/c-aa-11/     ------------->  /cps?tags=11
/c-aa-11-bb-22/ ------------->  /cps?tags=11,22 
/c-aa-11-bb-22-cc-21/  ------------->  /cps?tags=11,22,21
```

eg

So, how to rewrite with one regex

```
location ~* ^/c-(\w+)-(\d+) { 
     rewrite "/c-(\w+)-(\d+)(/?)$" /main/cps?tags=$2 last; 
}
```